# Encountered: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons

Tags: reactjs, react-konva

I was creating a project with React and Konva.js but faced the error of "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

".

The code I am using is :

```
import React from "react";
import { Rect, Transformer } from "react-konva";
const Rectangle = ({ shapeProps, isSelected, onSelect, onChange }) => {
  const shapeRef = React.useRef();
  const trRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isSelected) {
      // we need to attach transformer manually
      trRef.current.setNode(shapeRef.current);
      trRef.current.getLayer().batchDraw();
    }
  }, [isSelected]);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Rect
        onClick={onSelect}
        ref={shapeRef}
        {...shapeProps}
        draggable
        onDragEnd={(e) => {
          onChange({
            ...shapeProps,
            x: e.target.x(),
            y: e.target.y(),
          });
        }}
        onTransformEnd={(e) => {
          // transformer is changing scale
          const node = shapeRef.current;
          const scaleX = node.scaleX();
          const scaleY = node.scaleY();
          node.scaleX(1);
          node.scaleY(1);
          onChange({
            ...shapeProps,
            x: node.x(),
            y: node.y(),
            width: node.width() * scaleX,
            height: node.height() * scaleY,
          });
        }}
      />
      {isSelected && <Transformer ref={trRef} />}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Rectangle;
```

The error says that there is a problem with

```
const shapeRef = React.useRef();
  const trRef = React.useRef();
```

but I am unsure if it is a problem

Comment: Make sure you are using a version 16.8.0 or above of react and react-dom

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, hi Shubham, yeah I am using the latest version react and react-dom

Comment: Please run npm ls react and make sure that you use one version of react

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, after I run npm ls react I got react@16.13.1

Comment: @user13647380 what about `react-konva` version?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your versions of `react` and `react-konva` are matched. Usually, it is enough to just upgrade to the latest versions.